# How To Update A List After Using A Style Theme

Tags: android, coding-style, dialog

I have a list that fills up nicely after entering data from an input panel that uses a regular layout style.

But, if use a Dialog or Transparent style theme defined in the manifest for the activity, the list won't update until go back to the parent activity that called the list activity.

One: Why is this different than when using a standard layout?

Two: How can I update the list when finished with the dialog?  Note: I've tried onResume, onRestart, onthis and onthat and oneverything else... but, it doesn't take care of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ask the list to re-render itself by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the Adapter you used to fill the List with.

If your Activity is a sub-class of ListActivity then you might need to call

```
getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks - no problem calling the notifyDataSetChanged - But, it didn't work.  No luck calling the getAdapter.  My adapter is called fillMe, so I'm calling:   fillMe.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();  Perhaps I'm not calling it correctly?